# kafka-topics with bootstrap-server gives UnknownTopicOrPartitionException, but with zookeeper does not?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

What are the differences between these?

```
kafka-topics.sh --describe --bootstrap-server kafka1:6667


kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zoo_server:2181 --describe
```

We have Apache Kafka version - 2.7. As I know Newer versions of Kafka no longer requires ZooKeeper connection string to described topics, but can directly go via the Kafka brokers

but when I use the CLI as:

```
kafka-topics.sh --describe --bootstrap-server kafka1:6667
```

sometimes we get exception as ( most of the times we get the right describe info )

```
This server does not host this topic-partition.
```

or full ERROR as:

```
[2022-01-16 10:32:27,169] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownTopicOrPartitionException: This server does not host this topic-partition.
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
```

but when we are using the following cli

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zoo_server:2181 --describe
```

then described output is fine

full broker properties file:

```
auto.create.topics.enable=false
auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true
background.threads=10
log.retention.bytes=-1
log.retention.hours=12
delete.topic.enable=true
leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=300
leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage=10
log.dir=/var/kafka/kafka-data
log.flush.interval.messages=9223372036854775807
log.flush.interval.ms=1000
log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms=60000
log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms=9223372036854775807
log.flush.start.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms=60000
compression.type=producer
log.roll.jitter.hours=0
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.segment.delete.delay.ms=60000
message.max.bytes=1000012
min.insync.replicas=1
num.io.threads=8
num.network.threads=3
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
num.replica.fetchers=1
offset.metadata.max.bytes=4096
offsets.commit.required.acks=-1
offsets.commit.timeout.ms=5000
offsets.load.buffer.size=5242880
offsets.retention.check.interval.ms=600000
offsets.retention.minutes=10080
offsets.topic.compression.codec=0
offsets.topic.num.partitions=50
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
offsets.topic.segment.bytes=104857600
queued.max.requests=500
quota.consumer.default=9223372036854775807
quota.producer.default=9223372036854775807
replica.fetch.min.bytes=1
replica.fetch.wait.max.ms=500
replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms=5000
replica.lag.time.max.ms=10000
replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes=65536
replica.socket.timeout.ms=30000
request.timeout.ms=30000
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
transaction.max.timeout.ms=900000
transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size=5242880
transaction.state.log.min.isr=2
transaction.state.log.num.partitions=50
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.segment.bytes=104857600
transactional.id.expiration.ms=604800000
unclean.leader.election.enable=false
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=600000
zookeeper.max.in.flight.requests=10
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=600000
zookeeper.set.acl=false
broker.id.generation.enable=true
connections.max.idle.ms=600000
connections.max.reauth.ms=0
controlled.shutdown.enable=true
controlled.shutdown.max.retries=3
controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms=5000
controller.socket.timeout.ms=30000
default.replication.factor=2
delegation.token.expiry.time.ms=86400000
delegation.token.max.lifetime.ms=604800000
delete.records.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=1
fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=1000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=3000
group.max.session.timeout.ms=1800000
group.max.size=2147483647
group.min.session.timeout.ms=6000
log.213`1234cleaner.backoff.ms=15000
log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size=134217728
log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=86400000
log.cleaner.enable=true
log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor=0.9
log.cleaner.io.buffer.size=524288
log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second=1.7976931348623157e308
log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms=9223372036854775807
log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio=0.5
log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms=0
log.cleaner.threads=1
log.cleanup.policy=delete
log.index.interval.bytes=4096
log.index.size.max.bytes=10485760
log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms=9223372036854775807
log.message.timestamp.type=CreateTime
log.preallocate=false
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
max.connections=2147483647
max.connections.per.ip=2147483647
max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots=1000
num.partitions=1
producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=1000
queued.max.request.bytes=-1
replica.fetch.backoff.ms=1000
replica.fetch.max.bytes=1048576
replica.fetch.response.max.bytes=10485760
reserved.broker.max.id=1500
transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms=60000
transaction.remove.expired.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms=3600000
zookeeper.sync.time.ms=2000
broker.rack=/default-rack

### kafka hosts variables #########
broker.id=1001
listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafka1.udekdeju.com:6667
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT.HOST:PLAINTEXT
inter.broker.listener.name=PLAINTEXT
zookeeper.connect=120.64.162.15:2181,120.64.163.42:2181,120.64.163.73:2181

#### kafka finalize version update #####
log.message.format.version=2.7.1
inter.broker.protocol.version=2.7.1
```